# Concatenating character arrays in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, character

I have been requested to read a file from standard in like:

```
./gscheck < testfile
```

Where gscheck is the name of my compiled executable. Anyways, I need to use the function cin.getline() to read each line into a character array. I know how to do this,

```
char line[250];
while (cin.getline(line, 250))
{
    Do stuff;
}
```

But ultimately, I do not want to do anything per line, I want to concatenate every line into one gigantic character array. How can I, using the above methods, create a larger character array that contains each line in order and includes the newline breaks, such that I am essentially 'slurping' from the file, and then parsing it character by character, but not using the string class.

Comment: What is limiting your ability to use `std::string`?

Comment: Its an assignment, requested of me to do it this stupid way...

Comment: Do you *have* to use cin.getline? It can be done, but it'd be evil.

Comment: if it is homework, please tag your question as such

Comment: @catchmeifyoutry if you didn't see, SO is trying to remove the homework tag.  See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated

Comment: @JKor hey thanks, I didn't know that, reading up on it now ;)

Answer (score 1):

How about this then:

```
char file[2000];
char *end=file+1998;
char *ptr=file;
while (!cin.eof() && ptr < end) {
  cin.getline(ptr, end-ptr)
  ptr += strlen(ptr);
  *ptr++ = "\n";
  *ptr = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you have limitation not to use dynamic memory, Which std::string is using for sure:

```
char a[VERY_BIG_SIZE_ENOUGH_FOR_FILE];
std::cin.read(a, VERY_BIG_SIZE_JUST_ENOUGH_FOR_FILE - 1);
a[VERY_BIG_SIZE_JUST_ENOUGH_FOR_FILE - 1] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 1):

Based off of @KerrekSB's answer, you could use the deprecated `std::ostrstream`, which uses character arrays (actually a `char *`, but with `strlen` you can get it to work easily as an array).

```
std::ostrstream oss;
oss <<std::cin.rdbuf();
return oss.str();
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it.

Just say no.

Don't use "character arrays".

Seriously.

Use `std::string`.

```
std::string result;

for (std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line); )
{
    result += line;
}
```

But if you just want to read *everything* and not actually parse lines (and instead *preserve* newlines), it might be even simpler to access the input buffer directly:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << std::cin.rdbuf();
return oss.str();
```

Comment: -1 This is obviously a homework assignment and beginners *should* be using lower level methods before defaulting to the STL